# Twilio SMS/Python, trying to capture the body of an SMS

Tags: python, twilio

This is my first post here so sorry if anything is not correct. I have been trying to retrieve the body of an SMS through twilio. The end goal is to have a basic chat-bot that I can use over text however I did not want to code everything within the one Python file. Thats the purpose for pulling it out.

I am looking for some guidance on where I should be heading next.
To start here is the error(s):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
print (sms_reply().message_body)
File "/home/pi/PythonScripts/BasicSMSBot/SMSIncoming.py", line 18, in 
sms_reply
message_body = request.form['Body']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, 
in __getattr__
return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, 
in _get_current_object
return self.__local()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 37, in 
_lookup_req_object
raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

As it seams there is something wrong with the way I am wanting to pull the body out.

Here is the code currently in SMSIncoming:

```
#importing nessisary scripts and files
import os
#import SMSOutgoing
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse


#initilizing the global user variable
#glo_user_var = (' T ');

#initilizing app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def sms_reply():
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    #body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    message_body = request.form['Body']
    #for debuging the SMS instercept
    #saveFile = open('bodyfile.txt', 'w')
    #saveFile.write(body)
    #saveFile.close()

    resp.message("Testting the SMS responce")
    return str(resp)
    return str(body)



    #lets main app process run
    if __name__ == "__main__":
           app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the code currently in main.py

```
   #place all imports and scripts to be run
   import os
   import SMSOutgoing
   from SMSIncoming import sms_reply
   #from SMSIncoming.py import app, sms_reply
   import time



   #call up ngrok and make server on port 5000
   #os.system("./ngrok http 5000");


   #start running the SMSIncoming app
   #if __name__ == "__main__":
   #       app.run(debug=True)

   #       have to start apps separately!  #


   #this block will handle incoming SMS (User Input)
   while True:
   #       global glo_user_var
          print (sms_reply().message_body)
          #file = open('test_user_input.txt', 'w')
          #file.write(glo_user_var)
          #file.close()
          time.sleep(1)
```

Everything in main.py is either commented out or in place for testing.

The reason I want to print the body is to make sure that it is getting to where I want it to be. After that I would use it as the users input which would define the reply.

I am also using ngrok to be my http webhook.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, the problem that you are having is because you are breaking the flask app up into multiple files and attempting to call a function that is also a route once a second. So, you definitely need to drop the `while True` loop to start with.

Next, I understand that you can see that things might become overwhelming if you build the entire application in one file. However you are currently prematurely optimising. I recommend you get it working first in one file then refactor the application into more manageable chunks.

For the record, you are doing the right thing to get the SMS message's body. The [Twilio message webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) will send the body as the form parameter `Body` so you will be able to get hold of that parameter within a response to that request using

```
message_body = request.form['Body']
```

Once you get to that stage, take a look at this documentation from Flask on [building larger applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/) and then the information on [building modular applications with Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#blueprints).